How can I convert a Pivot table in Epplus to a normal table in C#?
I am using Epplus to export some data into an Excel spreadsheet. For one sheet, I made a chart using that data and it works just fine. For another sheet of data I also need to make a chart, but in order to do this, I needed to pivot the table, which is fine. That pivot code is below:
    var specPivotTable = specificationPivot.PivotTables.Add(specificationPivot.Cells["A1"], specificationSheet.Cells["A1:I" + specificationSheet.Dimension.End.Row], "SpecPivot");
    var contractor = specPivotTable.ColumnFields.Add(specPivotTable.Fields["Name"]);
    var directCost = specPivotTable.DataFields.Add(specPivotTable.Fields["Total Direct Cost"]);
    var specRows = specPivotTable.RowFields.Add(specPivotTable.Fields["Specification"]);
    specPivotTable.DataOnRows = true;
    specPivotTable.Calculate(true);

This works fine and produces the pivot table. I can then make the chart based on the pivot table iteself. So far so good.
However, here is where I run into a problem. This export is done in one of our applications, so when someone exports the data and then opens the Excel file, Excel defaults to a protected view based on the fact it was downloaded from the internet. The first sheet and it's chart show up fine. The second sheet of data shows up fine as well. However, the sheet with the pivot table doesn't show the pivot table, and the chart is not populated either. Once I click the "Enable Editing" button, the pivot table shows up and so does the chart.This is a problem, because we can't expect our users to do this, it's not obvious that you need to click that button.
So, is there a way in EPPlus to take the raw pivot data and copy it to a new sheet? I could then make the chart based on the copy, which would make it behave more like the first sheet and chart. I did see one SO post that supposedly showed how to do this, but when I tried the code, all it did was un-pivot the data,
So, just to be clear, what I would like to do is save the pivoted data to a new sheet, as a normal table.Is it possible to do this?
